# Target an element in Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote this code so when the user is at the password textbox, he/she can press enter to log in. However, I think because it is in the bootstrap modal so I couldn't target it with jQuery selector. Any idea? 
 
Here is the HTML:

```
                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">

                      <!-- header -->
                      <div class="modal-header"> 
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                      </div>

                      <!-- body -->
                      <div class="modal-body text-center" >
                          <input class='form-control' type="text" id="userName" placeholder="Username" ng-model='username'>
                          <input class='form-control' type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model='password'>

                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id ="loginButton" ng-click="goToAdminPanel()">Login</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeButton">Close</button>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                 </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

And the jQuery

```
 $("input#password").keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#loginButton").click();
    console.log('This is enter');
}});
```

Comment: Probably not the solution, but try removing the space between in `id ="loginButton"`

Comment: can you please try putting `alert()` statement before `if(event.keyCode == 13)` condition.

Comment: I tried both and both did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should work.. unless you are generating the form after the script has ran.

try :-

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input#password', function(event){
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
       $("#loginButton").click();
       console.log('This is enter');
   }
});
```

or wire the event inside document.ready

```
$(function(){
   $("input#password").keyup(function(event){
      if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#loginButton").click();
        console.log('This is enter');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: The lower solution does not work.
The upper works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to solve this :

- [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)
- use the browser default behavior with forms and submit actions

I would suggest the latter as it doesn't need javascript and it would have better support with mobile browser for instance.

First, your code does not show a `<form>` tag although you use `<input>`, this looks like a bad practice.

Next, if your login button was the type `submit` instead of `button`, the enter key would automatically submit the parent form when pressed while a field is focused.

Then, you could either handle the `submit` event or not, depending on your use case.